# play 2.0 how to access error messages from Model

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have defined some Error Messages and my Question is, how to access them correctly?!

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

    @Constraints.Required(message="Start Date is required")
    public Date start;

}
```

Now, if you got a validation error in my controller save() method as you can see:

```
public class Tasks extends Controller {

    public static Result save() {
        Form<Task> filledForm = taskForm.bindFromRequest();
        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(
                    create.render("create", filledForm)
        }
    }

}
```

and now, in my view:

```
@if(taskForm.hasErrors) {
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            @taskForm.errors
        </div>
}
```

I get the error message on the screen like this:

```
{name=[ValidationError(start, Start Date is required,[])]}
```

So, how can I access now the "Start Date is required"-message directly? I think the "@taskForm.erros" is a map, but I'm not sure.

Thank you very much.

Cheers,

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`errors()`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L474) method indeed returns a `Map`, to be specific a `Map<String, List<ValidationError>>`.

To access the message directly use the method [`error(String key)`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L481). So in this case use `@taskForm.get("start")`